# Batch script find files in a directory

Tags: file, batch-file, directory

I need to find all find with extension *.job in a specific folder. But somehow my code not work. However it works when i change *.job to specific name such as INV.job?

```
if exist "C:\WatchFolder\Incoming\*.job" (
 copy /Y /V "C:\WatchFolder\Incoming\*.job" "C:\WatchFolder\InProgress"
 ECHO TRIGGER AUTOMATIONS
)
```

Thank for reading

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
dir "C:\WatchFolder\Incoming\*.job" >nul 2>&1 && (
 copy /Y /V "C:\WatchFolder\Incoming\*.job" "C:\WatchFolder\InProgress"
 ECHO TRIGGER AUTOMATIONS
)
```

`if exist` does only work for a specific file, not with wild cards `*` and `?`. `copy` works with wild cards.

Comment: It would be good to explain why `dir &&` works and what the redirection is for.

Comment: `dir` sets an errorlevel <> 0 if it fails and `&&` executes the following commands only if errorlevel=0. Redirection is for cosmetics, it supresses 1) the normal output and 2) the error messages.